# PHP not identifying ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a PHP script which is displaying a drop-down box.Now when I select a drop down box an ajax call is made to the PHP script , which works fine , I can see in firebug that the call has been made and correct parameter is passed.I am using this code in php to identify if the call has been made

```
isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
       ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest')
```

But this check always fails and I do not get any response.How can I debug this?

Comment: And what value is actually in `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you check in firebug -net tab - if the header HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH is being sent?

Comment: @scrum awesome , I do not see it anywhere in  header sub tab of the net tab in firebug.I have  read that $_SERVER is not a php variable but is generated by the web server , so if it generated by webserver then how can we control it?

Comment: $_SERVER is a php variable that gets populated by the server. what are you using to sent the AJAX call?

Comment: @scrum I am using this code , i am not sure if i should set the header or not.xmlhttp.open("GET","index.php?name="+name,true);
    //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
    xmlhttp.send();

Comment: by default it will not send the header. use `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X_REQUESTED_WITH','XMLHttpRequest');`